# Remove part of an array if its not contain

Tags: php, arrays, remove-if

I have an array in php called $json. It looks like this

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [name] => Knife 
    [url] => http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/753/297120... 
    [price] => 0.16 USD 
    [image] => http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/imag...
    [quantity] => 30 
    [game] => Counter-Strike: Global Offensive ) 

[1] => Array ( 
    [name] => Strange Knife 
    [url] => http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Strange%2...
    [price] => 0.55 USD 
    [image] => http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/imag... 
    [quantity] => 177 
    [game] => Team Fortress 2 ) 

[2] => Array ( 
    [name] => Festive Knife 
    [url] => http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Festive%20Knife" id="resultlink_2 
    [price] => 3.72 USD 
    [image] => http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqffx
    [quantity] => 66 
    [game] => Team Fortress 2 ) 

[3] => Array ( 
    [name] => â… Flip Knife 
    [url] => http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/7
    [price] => 3.72 USD 
    [image] => http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqffx
    [quantity] => 24 
    [game] => Counter-Strike: Global Offensive ) 

...
```

How I can remove a part of an array where GAME != "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive" ?

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you just want us to do your homework?!

Comment: `$json = array_filter($json, function($value) { return $value['game'] === 'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive'; });`

Comment: Use "strpos" PHP function for each element of the array: https://php.net/manual/ro/function.strpos.php

Comment: Thanks for replay .Its not my homework, am doing it for myself . I searched a lot on stackoverflow and google but cant find and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array; // Your array.

foreach($array as $subarray) {
    if($subarray['game'] != "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive") {
        unset($subarray);
    }
}
```